# When do I not need to specify File's Owner for a nib?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder

I have been reading up on File's Owner here on Stack Overflow and a few other resources, but I was left with one question. When do I not need a File's Owner for a nib? In chapter 8 of *Exploring the iPhone SDK* (a great book by the way) you design a table view cell nib. The author says the following:

> You might be wondering why we're not doing anything with the File's Owner icon. The reason is that we just don't need to. We're using this table cell to display data, but all the interaction with the user is going to go through the table view, so it doesn't need its own controller class. We're really just using the nib as a sort of template so we can design our table cells visually.

This does not make sense to me. I was under the impression that all nib files needed a File's Owner, but obviously my understanding of this concept is not complete. Can someone restate when and why I don't need to worry about File's Owner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going by what you quoted, the book says that your File's Owner is using the objects in the nib, but the objects in the nib are not using File's Owner, so you don't really need to configure File's Owner at all in IB.

You always have a File's Owner, because *something* is loading the nib, and that something is the File's Owner.

More to the point, even if the objects in the nib are not using the FO now, you may change them later to do so, so you might as well configure the FO every time.

Configuring the FO in IB also makes accessing the objects in the nib easier. Once you tell IB what class the FO is, you can create outlet variables in your header, and IB will detect them automatically; then you can connect those outlets in IB and access the objects by those outlet variables in your code.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, File's Owner is always set, but if your nib does not need to communicate anything back to the rest of the program you don't to use File's Owner for outlets or targets. Is that correct?

Comment: You kind of make it sound like you can't have outlets if you don't use File's Owner, which isn't the case (I'm sure you're aware of this, too).  In general, setting the class for File's Owner works great if you're subclassing one of the NS*Controller classes.

Comment: You would still set the FO as the target of actions, and you can even still bind to the FO. And yes, you can manually add outlets in IB, but I find it easier to just set the class once and let IB auto-detect outlets (and flag stale outlet connections!) thereafter.

Comment: (Well, you can bind on the Mac. Not on the iPhone.)

Comment: IB will automatically detect outlets/actions in other custom classes you make (you just add an NSObject and set its class).  Or am I misreading you?

Comment: We're talking about the File's Owner. You don't add an object; the File's Owner is already there, because it's *always* there. And yes, you need to set its class for IB to auto-detect its outlets—that's what I said in my answer.